# Limit $\lim_{x \to0^-}\ln x$

Tags: limits

Can i ask for the limit as $x$ approaches $\lim_{x \to 0-}\ln x$? Please explain. Its because since the limit of a function only exists if the lim as $x$ approaches some number $n$ from both the positive and negative side is the same, im not sure that im convinced that the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ for $\ln x$ exists. i know its negative infinity from the positive side, but from the negative side?

Answer (score 6):

The domain of $\ln(x)$ is only positive reals, so the left-hand limit at 0 doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Maybe OP meant complex Log?

Comment: @WilliamStagner what would possibly make you think that though?

Comment: Because every calculus student in the world has seen the graph $y=\ln x$.

Answer (score 1):

For a limit to exist, the two limits approaching from the left and right side need to match up.

I.e. we need $$\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\ln(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\ln(x)$$ to be true.

Since $\ln(x)$ is not defined for $x\leq 0$ assuming we are evaluating over the reals, the left-hand limit can't be evaluated, and thus the limit does not exist.

If you are evaluating over the complex numbers, that's a *somewhat* different story, but given your wording, I've assumed that we're talking about the reals here.